# Running total of a conditional measure not working using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

i have the below simple dataset where i have a measure called "slot".The "new slot" measure is derived from slot column (if gap is <0, new slot is 0 else slot) . I want to calculate the running total of new slot but no help. Same working for Slot field but not working for new slot.

I tried:  CALCULATE([new slot], FILTER( ALLEXCEPT(table,table[Product Family]), table[month]<=MAX(table[month]) ) )

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First convert the [Month] to a more useful format like YYMM and keep it as number (or even better use a Calendar table with a relation to this data table). For this example I've added a column using power query which is [YYMM] in Int64.Type-format.

Then you can write the following measure:

```
Running SLot = 
var fam = MAX('Data'[Prod Fam])
var currentYYMM = MAX('Data'[YYMM])

return
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Data[New Slot]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Data'),
        'Data'[Prod Fam] = fam && 'Data'[YYMM] <= currentYYMM
    )
)
```

This takes product family into account.

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot OscarLar. The solution helped me clarifying the basics.

Answer (score 0):

First create an Index column in Power Query[image]

Use the following DAX measure to calculate running total

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ashok for providing the solution. since i am using direct query, i created index column using rankx and i included the logic for product family.